# JavaScript getter and setter on dojo defined class do not work as expected

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have defined a "class" in dojo, with a property `foo` with defined 
JavaScript `getter`and `setter`.

In the code below, setter is never being called and getter is called twice.

I would like to know:

- Why this happen ONLY on when defining a dojo "class"?
- How to fix it?

I am aware of dojo custom getter and setter, but I'am interested in understanding why does not work in this "class".

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/yz8ft4eh/

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
  var Person = declare(null, {
    _foo: null,
    get foo() {
      console.log('getter foo ' + this._foo);
      return this._foo;
    },
    set foo(value) {
      console.log('setter foo ' + value);
      this._foo = value;
    },
    constructor: function(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.foo = 1000;
    }
  });
  var folk = new Person("phiggins");
  folk.foo = 2000;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Dojo doesn't understand that you have a getter/setter property there. It's important to remember that a **lot** of Dojo was written a long time ago, before even the ES5 spec in 2009 was released. While the project is active, there's only so much time in the day and they may not have time to go back and retrofit support for newer things everywhere. (That said, I'm surprised this remains an issue in 2016, seven years after getter/setter properties were added to JavaScript.)

I can't find uncompressed source online for v1.10.4 (the one in your fiddle), but I can find [1.10.6](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.6/dojo.js.uncompressed.js), and it uses a simple `for-in` loop to copy your properties. We can see that `declare` calls `safeMixin`, which does this:

```
for (name in source) {
    t = source[name];
    if ((t !== op[name] || !(name in op)) && name != cname) {
        if (opts.call(t) == "[object Function]") {
            // non-trivial function method => attach its name
            t.nom = name;
        }
        target[name] = t;
    }
}
```

To support using getter/setter properties, it would have to be using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertydescriptor) or similar there. So instead of copying your property properly, it's just reading the value of it.

You can solve that by initializing the property in your `constructor` instead:

```js
require(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
  function getFoo() {
    console.log('getter foo ' + this._foo);
    return this._foo;
  }
  function setFoo(value) {
    console.log('setter foo ' + value);
    this._foo = value;
  }
  var Person = declare(null, {
    _foo: null,
    constructor: function(name) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, "foo", {
        get: getFoo,
        set: setFoo
      });
      this.name = name;
      this.foo = 1000;
    }
  });
  var folk = new Person("phiggins");
  folk.foo = 2000;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for your explanation.